# Can't generate pot file using wp cli

Tags: translation, wp-cli

I'm developing a child theme and I want to get `.pot` file using `wp-cli`.

I follow the [wp-cli handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/installing/) and run:

```
cd /media/sf_TOOLS/ubuntu-20.04/bin
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

then in the folder where are theme files I run:

```
/media/sf_TOOLS/ubuntu-20.04/bin/wp-cli.phar i18n make-pot --domain=test-child . languages/test-child.pot
```

This command generate a `.pot` file without theme strings:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-12-29T09:38:20+01:00\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"X-Generator: WP-CLI 2.4.0\n"
"X-Domain: test-child\n"
```

so using `--debug` option I got this log:

```
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (1.419s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (1.419s)
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /media/sf_TOOLS/ubuntu-20.04/bin/wp-cli.phar i18n make-pot --debug --domain=test-child . languages/test-child.pot (1.419s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: / (1.447s)
Debug (hooks): Processing hook "before_run_command" with 1 callbacks (1.463s)
Debug (hooks): On hook "before_run_command": WP_CLI\Bootstrap\RegisterDeferredCommands->add_deferred_commands() (1.463s)
Debug (bootstrap): Running command: i18n make-pot (1.463s)
Debug (make-pot): No valid theme stylesheet or plugin file found, treating as a regular project. (1.603s)
Debug (make-pot): Extracting all strings with text domain "test-child" (1.604s)
Debug (make-pot): Destination: languages/test-child.pot (1.604s)
Debug (make-pot): Excluding the following files: node_modules,.git,.svn,.CVS,.hg,vendor,Gruntfile.js,webpack.config.js,*.min.js (2.047s)
Debug (make-pot): Extracted 0 strings (2.151s)
```

It seems that: `No valid theme stylesheet or plugin file found`.

In the folder where I run `wp-cli` there is a file `style.css` that contains:

```
/* 
Theme Name: Test Child
Theme URI: https://www.example.com/
Author: Test Author 
Author URI: https://www.example.com/
Description: Child Theme just for test.
Tags: translation-ready, custom-background, theme-options, custom-menu, threaded-comments, featured-images, footer-widgets, editor-style, right-sidebar, full-width-template, two-columns, grid-layout, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-logo, featured-image-header, portfolio, news, entertainment
Version: 1.0.8
Requires at least: 5.0
Tested up to: 5.4.1
Requires PHP: 5.6
License: Test License
License URI: https://www.example.com/test_license.html
Text Domain: test-child
Template: test
*/
```

Theme file that contains strings to be translated is in `admin` sub-folder, here is an example of string that I expect to see in `.pot` file:

```
<button type="button" class="button rnc-user-image_remove <?php if ( empty($userImage) ) { echo 'hidden'; } ?>"><?php _e('Remove this image', 'test-child'); ?></button>
```

I've also tested in my wordpress development site running command in:

```
wp-content/themes/test-child
```

but I got the same result.

What is wrong here?

Here is `wp-cli --info` result:

```
$ /media/sf_TOOLS/ubuntu-20.04/bin/wp-cli.phar --info
OS: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php7.4
PHP version:    7.4.3
php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /media/sf_TEST/test-child
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
```

I got the same result running the command on a theme downloaded from official repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that Wordpress project folder is a shared folder on Ubuntu VirtualBox guest OS with guest additions.

Searching in wp cli source code, I found that to scan the directory is used:

```
$files = new IteratorIterator( new DirectoryIterator( $this->source ) );
```

and I could verify that it returns only `.` and `..` files.

Moving Wordpress project files, for example, in `$HOME` directory and it works as expected.

`make-pot` needs `mbstring` package, so I have to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

I don't know if it is a php bug or a Ubuntu bug, but on local filesystem it works.